# Automatically Add To iTunes sending .m4v to Home Movies folder

Tags: itunes, windows

I updated iTunes to version 11 recently on my Windows 7 machine and now when I add Handbrake encoded movies (.m4v) via "Automatically Add To iTunes" it is moving those movies to the "Home Movies" section instead of "Movies".  Prior to iTunes 11 I could add an .m4v to that folder and it would put them in the "Movies" folder.

Is there a way to revert that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in Get Info > Options to change it from being a Home Movie into being a Movie.